# How to superscript text on \rightarrowtail?

Tags: arrows, superscripts, xrightarrow

How to get superscripted text on `\rightarrowtail`? I have included `mathtools` package, but there isn't any command like `\xrightarrowtail[]{}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not extensible, but still may suit.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,stackengine}
\newcommand\Rightarrowtail[2][]{\ensurestackMath{\mathrel{%
  \stackengine{1pt}{%
    \stackengine{0pt}{\rightarrowtail}{\scriptstyle#2}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}%
  }{\scriptstyle#1}{U}{c}{F}{F}{S}%
}}}
\begin{document}
\[x \xrightarrow[a]{b} y\]
\[x \Rightarrowtail[a]{b} y\]
\end{document}
```

[image]